# Uninstall AD role from windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am trying to uinstall AD from windows 2008 and following the link provided http://www.rebeladmin.com/2016/10/step-step-guide-migrate-active-directory-fsmo-roles-windows-server-2012-r2-windows-server-2016/

Trying to run the following command

```
Uninstall-ADDSDomainController -DemoteOperationMasterRole -RemoveApplicationPartition
```

If you go down the part of uninstalling AD role, I get commands not found in powershell.  I have searched and says that windows server 2008 doesn't support this, but windows server 2008 R2 does.

What would be the similar actions needed to accomplish the task?  I do run dcpromo and demote?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=2852 tried to download this update and says it doesn't apply to my system.

Answer (score 0):

Also try removing the roles from Server Manager. Another option is to remove from network, then perform metadata cleanup to remove it from active directory.

[Clean up Active Directory Domain Controller server metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/ad-ds-metadata-cleanup)